# C++ How to call a function from another file with the same name as a function in another file when both are included?

Tags: c++, function

I am wondering how I could call a function from another file with the same name as a function in another file when both are included.
Example:

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
start();
return 0;
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H
#pragma once
int start();

#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int start()
{
//code here
return 0;
}
```

b.h

```
#ifndef _B_H
#define _Win32_H
#pragma once
int start();

#endif
```

b.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int start()
{
//code here
return 0;
}
```

the start(); in main.cpp will use start(); from a.h but I want it to use start(); from b.h
How do I do to select start(); in b.h?

Comment: A) you have no classes here. B) you can't distinguish the two functions. Use namespaces.

Comment: Use namespace, if you cant create class.

Comment: Sorry accidently called files for class. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the functions are defined in the respective `.cpp` files, i.e., one is defined in `a.cpp` and one in `b.cpp`, then this cannot happen. Once you try to link your code, you will get the error that `start()` is defined twice. Therefore, you do not have to reason about how to call one of them; the code will not link anyway unless the two functions are the same (i.e. defined in the same cpp file). If this is the case, then it doesn't matter which one is called (as there is only one).